# CURL GET escaping double quote

Tags: url, curl, get, escaping

I am trying to sending GET request to retrieve JSON result.

This one worked prefectly for me:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: */*" -X GET 'http://10.50.227.58:30000/api/v1/query?query=sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes)by(container_name,pod_name)&start=1598860800&end=1598860859';echo
```

However, what I need is below, and no matter how it failed with whatever I tried(for example, ", using %22) etc..

```
curl -i -H "Accept: */*" -X GET 'http://10.50.227.58:30000/api/v1/query?query=sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{container_name!="POD"})by(container_name,pod_name)&start=1598860800&end=1598860859';echo
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to encode URL with [--data-urlencode](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode)

```
curl -G -X GET \
       --data-urlencode 'query=sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{container_name!="POD"})by(container_name,pod_name)' \
       --data-urlencode 'start=1598860800' \
       --data-urlencode 'end=1598860859' \
       http://10.50.227.58:30000/api/v1/query
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
\"
```

or

```
'\"'
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'hello'\"'world'
hello"world
```

Or first escape with double quotes and then inside with single quotes

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, both did not work...